# errores al usar clases

Tags: c++, clase

estoy haciendo un código que opera vectores de R3 y me salen varios errores que no se como solucionar

**ERROR**

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'Vector3d&' from
> expression of type 'float [3]'

dentro de direccion() en el return direct;

> error: 'mag' was not declared in this scope

en direccion() dentro del for cuando pongo direct, se que no la he declarado pero no se como

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'Vector3d&' from
> expression of type 'float'

dentro de Vector3d& magnitud() en return mag; , el error es en mag

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'Vector3d&' from
> expression of type 'std::vector

dentro Vector3d& direccion() en la linea de return v; el error es en la v

```
class Vector3d
{
    private:
    vector<float> v;

    public:
        Vector3d()
            : v{1,2,3}
        {
        }
    ~Vector3d()=default;

    Vector3d& escalado(double esca )
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            v[i]=esca*v[i];
        }
        return v;
    }

    Vector3d& magnitud()
    {
        int i,raiz;
        float mag;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            raiz=raiz+v[i];
        }
        mag=sqrt(raiz);
        return mag;
    }
    Vector3d& direccion()
    {
        float direct[3];
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            direct[i]=v[i]/mag;
        }
        return direct;
    }
```

Comment: Estas devolviendo un `std::vector<float>`, y el tipo de retorno es `Vector3d&`. De hecho en todas las funciones estas retornando un tipo diferente al de la declaracion. Solo tienes que corregir eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'Vector3d&' from expression of type 'float [3]'

Esto:

```
    Vector3d()
        : v{1,2,3}
```

Debería ser así:

```
    Vector3d()
        : v{{1,2,3}}
```

Si te fijas, `std::vector` no tiene ningún constructor que acepte 3 elementos ... sin embargo si dispone de un constructor que admite una `initializer_list`. Pues eso, el juego de llaves exterior invoca al constructor de `std::vector`, mientras que el juego de llaves interior crea la lista de inicialización.

> error: 'mag' was not declared in this scope

```
Vector3d& direccion()
{
    float direct[3];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        direct[i]=v[i]/mag;
    }
    return direct;
}
```

Efectivamente, `mag` ni es una variable miembro de `Vector3d` ni tampoco es una variable local de `direccion`. `mag` entiendo que es un valor que debería devolver `magnitud`, luego la solución rápida sería la siguiente:

```
Vector3d& direccion()
{
    float mag = magnitud();
}
```

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'Vector3d&' from expression of type 'float'

```
Vector3d& direccion()
{
    float direct[3];
    return direct;
}
```

¿Cómo se convierte un array de `float` en un objeto de tipo `Vector3d`? O creas un constructor en `Vector3d` que acepte un array de `float` o creas directamente un `Vector3d` en esta función y lo rellenas.

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'Vector3d&' from expression of type 'std::vector

```
Vector3d& magnitud()
{
    float mag;
    return mag;
}
```

La firma dice que `magnitud` devuelve una referencia a `Vector3d` y la implementación intenta devolver un `float`. Como no hay un constructor en `Vector3d` que acepte un único `float`, el compilador se queja porque no sabe convertir `mag` en un objeto de tipo `Vector3d`. Entiendo que aquí la solución sería que `magnitud` devolviese un `float`:

```
float magnitud()
{
    // ...
```